# The readFile html parameter returns null in node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

When I run the code below, it brings back an error. I console.logged the html that was being sent in as a parameter and it returned null. How would i integrate a html file.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var hostname = '127.0.0.1'
var port = 3000;

fs.readFile("myFile.html", function(html, err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        //says that everything is OK and working
        res.statusCode = 200;
        //Sets content type 
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        //Writes html
        res.write(html);
        //Ends 
        res.end();
    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log("Server Started on port " + port);
    });
})
```

Comment: Why are you serving HTML as plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `fs.readFile`'s callback parameters mixed up. The *first* parameter is `err`, the *second* contains your data.

Change

```
fs.readFile("myFile.html", function(html, err) {
```

to

```
fs.readFile("myFile.html", function(err, html) {
```

Additionally, remember that HTML is not `text/plain`, it is `text/html`:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
```

Anyways, I am guessing that you are learning how to serve a website with Node. I would suggest checking out a library like [express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) which really makes it much less of a pain in the ass.

Comment: @M.A.Williams Glad I could help! Be sure to accept the answer by clicking on the [checkbox next to the answer](https://i.imgur.com/BvrkwLA.png).